Как сделать ссылку для перехода на определенное имя в html-таблице
Как сделать ссылку для перехода на определенное имя в html-таблице, размещенной на странице сайта. Нужно, чтобы найденное имя в ячейке подсвечивалось (любым способом, цвет, жирность, обводка и т.д.).
Если одинаковых имен в таблице несколько - то выделяется только самое верхнее имя или все одинаковые.
Варианты "ссылка на строку" - не подходят, т.к. наименования товаров часто сдвигаются по строкам (вверх-вниз), при этом все наименования в таблице - всегда constanta.
